# UML diagrams: Showing inheritance of a vector of pointers to a class

Tags: uml

How would I go about showing that class A inherits a vector of pointers to Class B? Would I have an inheritance arrowhead to Vector, or to Class B?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "class A inherits some resource to class B". Either class B inherits from class A - in this case B [specializes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype) A (or, alternatively, A [generalizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superclass_%28computer_science%29#Subclasses_and_superclasses) B); or class A and class B share a resource - in this case it's called [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation).